# How can I dynamically test whether a value conforms to a Python Literal type?

Tags: python, typing

I would like to understand how to dynamically test whether a value conforms to a Literal type in Python. Suppose I have the following code:

```py
from typing import Literal

PossibleValues = Literal["a", "b"]

x = input()
```

I would like to use `isinstance`, but doing so gives me a TypeError:

```
>>> isinstance(x, PossibleValues)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../typing.py", line 720, in __instancecheck__
    return self.__subclasscheck__(type(obj))
  File "/.../typing.py", line 723, in __subclasscheck__
    raise TypeError("Subscripted generics cannot be used with"
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
```

I've found that I could use `get_args`, but this approach seems a little hacky.

```
>>> from typing import get_args
>>> x = input()
'c'
>>> x in get_args(PossibleValues)
False
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You cannot use `isinstance` because `Literal` isn't a real (runtime) type

Comment: Note, `x` would not be a valid value for `Literal["a", "b"]`, since it is of type `str`.

Comment: `mypy` takes the "literal' in `Literal` seriously. Given something like `def foo(x: PossibleValues): ...`, `foo("a")` and `foo("b")` are valid, but `x = "a"; foo(x)` is not.

Comment: Anyway, the approach you have seems reasonable enough. It is only hackey insofar as what you are trying to do is hackey.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what [I just came up with](https://gist.github.com/ryuheechul/3f26ac6eae0bbe9b508a1a6200ecb2da) and I'm pretty happy with it.

```py
"""
seems like hard coding is the only way to make literal type to accept anything to be literal
(which makes sense if you think about it)
"""

from typing import Any, Literal


my_literal_type = Literal["a", "b", "c"]


# I used `Any` type here but you could use `str` if you want to restrict the dynamic value's type to be `str` only
def guard_mlt(value: Any) -> my_literal_type:
    """
    only allow values in my_literal_type to pass
    and otherwise raise TypeError
    this requires hard coding the return values as it's explained at the top

    >>> guard_mlt('a')
    'a'
    >>> guard_mlt('b')
    'b'
    >>> guard_mlt('c')
    'c'
    >>> guard_mlt('d')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    TypeError: d is not in typing.Literal['a', 'b', 'c']
    """
    match value:
        case "a":
            return "a"
        case "b":
            return "b"
        case "c":
            return "c"

    raise TypeError(f"{value} is not in {my_literal_type}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod()
```

The (inevitable) downside is that you will need to come up with the guard function for every literal type.